# Which language to use for creating this desktop application?

Tags: java, desktop-application

I am willing to create a simple desktop application for myself which will be able to download wallpapers from various sites and which can set and rotate the desktop wallpaper. [ desktop manager kind of thing ].

Please suggest which programming language to choose for this application. I know java but don' mind learning any other language too.  How is Adobe air? Can i create this application using Adobe air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the application you are talking about in Java/C/C++ and many other languages.  Since you know Java I would stick to Java.

Comment: java for desktop application? ok i will go with you :)

Comment: Yes, if by when you say desktop you mean, stand alone program that can run on your desktop that has a JVM.